# How to evaluate index i in an if statement within a for loop in R?

Tags: r

I would like to create a new variable "Diff", which i-th value is the difference between the i-th value of the variable "Date" and the (i-1)th value of the variable "Date" itself.
Something like:

```
df$Date[2]-df$Date[1]
```

iterated over the sequence 1:lenght(df$Date).

Obviously there is a problem when i is initialized at i=1, because i-1=0.

Trying to avoid this problem, nesting an if...else... statement within a for loop, I cannot manage to have "if" evaluating "i".

R gives me a syntax error which does not exist if I change the "if" condition.

This is my first attempt:

```
for (i in 1:length(df$Date)) {
  if (i=1) {
     df$Diff[[i]]<-0
  } else {
  df$Diff[[i]]<-df$Date[[i]] - df$Date[[i-1]]
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
unexpected '}' in "  }"
```

which is the "}" closing the else statement.

This is one of the (dirty) solutions I have found (sintax and parenthesis are the same):

```
for (i in 1:length(df$Date)) {
    if (df$Date[i]==df$Date[1]) {
        df$Diff[[i]]<-0
    } else {
        df$Diff[[i]]<-df$Date[[i]] - df$Date[[i-1]]
    }
}
```

However, my question here is:
how can I directly evaluate the index (i, e.g.) of a for loop inside an if statement nested within the for loop?

Thank you for help and patience.

Comment: `if (i=1)` should be `if(i==1)`

Comment: What about `df$Diff[[1]]<-0` outside your loop and looping over `2:length(df$Date)`?

Comment: Please provide examples that are complete and reproducible.  See instructions at top of  [tag:r] tag regarding posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating inside a for loop is no problem:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  if (i  == 5) {print(i)}
  else {print("i is not 5")}
}
```

As @Martin Gal mentioned, the problem is that you set (i=1) and not (i==1). I think another way to accomplish what you want to do using dplyr would be this:

```
library(dplyr)
df$Diff[[1]] <- 0
df %>% 
  mutate(Diff = Date - lag(Date))
```

Comment: Should not it be
df$Diff[[1]] <-0
?

Thank you for the "=="

Answer (score 2):

You are reinventing the wheel here. You should just be able to do

```
diff(df$Date)
```

Of course, the resulting vector is shorter by one than the original vector, and it is up to you decide whether to leave it that way, or to stick a `0` or `NA` on the beginning or end of the result depending on what makes the most sense for your application.

For example, if I have a vector of cumulative daily Coronavirus cases called `covid`, and I wanted to know the number of new cases per day, I would do:

```
diff(c(0, covid))
```